# SonarQube: How to apply multiple quality profiles to one project?

Tags: java, android, sonarqube, kotlin

I would like to use [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org) 6.3.1 to analyze the Java and Kotlin code of an **Android** project. Therefore, I installed the *Android Lint* plugin besides the preinstalled *SonarJava* aka. *Sonar way* plugin. Both show up in the *Java* language dropdown in the *Administration* section of the project as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Project / Administration]

- How can I apply **multiple** profiles at the same time?
- Where can I find other profiles suitable for Java/Kotlin/Android projects?

---

## Related posts

- [Sonarqube: use multiple custom quality profiles for a single multilanguage project...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709054/sonarqube-use-multiple-custom-quality-profiles-for-a-single-multilanguage-proje)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You apply both profiles by creating a third profile that contains all the rules in each of your source profiles.

The easiest way to accomplish that is to

1. Go to Quality Profiles and create a new profile
2. Now in the list of profiles, click on the **rule count** for one of your source profiles. This takes you to the list of rules active in that profile
3. Use the **Bulk Change > Activate In...** option to turn those rules on in your new profile
4. Return to step 2 with the next source profile in your list.

Comment: Nice, thank you a lot. - I would love to see this feature a bit more intuitive or better discoverable in the documentation.